# I am getting an error in mule 3.7 maven dependencies

Tags: maven, mule

when i am trying to update the dependencies in maven it is throwing an error "There was an error running the studio:studio goal on project " please help me in this.

Comment: The project com.mycompany:sbs_poc1:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\SBS\SBS_WORKSPACE\sbs_poc1\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre7/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: Please add that error to your original post (click "edit" to do so). Also use code blocks for the error to be legible.

Comment: You can see my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614394/error-creating-a-maven-project/36075627#36075627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using mule-app-maven-plugin without configuring extensions to true. Try to edit your pom.xml and make the config look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: For me it is <extensions>true</extensions>. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

From the exception you're pasting in your comments, it looks like you're trying to build your Mule APP with a JRE, in this case you would need to build using a JDK, please make sure your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to a JDK and attempt the build.

Comment: I have set my JAVA_HOME and the installed JREs in the prefereces pointing to a JDK. But I still get the same error!