# Mule Maven - error running project with Maven

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

Trying to run project with Maven using Anypoint Studio IDE.

But I am getting this error in Console:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.mycompany:mymuleproject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (E:\worldspace\mymuleproject\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 9, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614394/error-creating-a-maven-project

Comment: Please, provide the pom.xml file and more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed Java JDK 6 instead of JRE 6. Then check if you have configured and checked your Java Runtime correctly (Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs).

Comment: Currently i am using Java JDK 1.8 instead of JRE8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? I've seen similar issues on that OS when not running the IDE as Administrator.

Does running `mvn clean package` in your project directory produce the same result?